# How to remove strange highlighting of UINavBar when scrolling UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a child navigation view controller with a collectionView embedded in it. When I scroll it, the navigation bar appears to be dimmed a bit.

It looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone know how to remove this behavior?

Comment: How you set your navigatiınBar. Could you please share some code?

Comment: Could you try: `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

Answer (score 2):

I was setting my navigation bar appearance globally like that:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
...

UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
```

But I finally managed to find the fix. You just have to add this:

```
appearance.backgroundEffect = nil
```

and the problem goes away.